# How to change the color of the Text in SearchView?

Tags: android, xml, searchview, android-theme

The color of the text in the searchView does not change

I tried to change the color of the text in the searchView by the `android:textColor` in the xml but it isn't working
I also tried to customize the style by adding this code to both dark and light themes file

```xml
 <style name="searchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="iconTint" tools:targetApi="o">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

and then attach it to the xml `style="@style/searchView"` in the searchView

This is my attributes that I defined for the SearchView in XML

```xml
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        style="@style/searchView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
        android:goIcon="@drawable/chevron_right"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:queryHint="Search headphone"
        android:searchHintIcon="@drawable/search"
        android:searchIcon="@drawable/search"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

The text is always grey in the dark theme but in the light theme it is black as normal